# Hygraph: TypeError: Expected `limit` to be a finite number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm running into issue with my Hygraph CMS that saying that not allow me to make request anymore.

So I have contact the support team over at **Hygraph CMS** to see if they would helped me figure this problem but having a hard time understand:

[image]

1. Setup my Throttling to allows you to fetch 1 concurrent request maximum, with a minimum delay of 0.5 seconds.

**I have read this blog:** https://hygraph.com/docs/api-reference/basics/rate-limits

An follow the step on how to setup my code correct to fetch the request so I can get an delay of 0.5 sec but had to bring up becuase an error message that getting TypeError: Expected `limit` to be a finite number.

GraphQL data can be fetched using the code below. It is from Hygraph CMS that we want this information, but prior to that, I was fetching the url with the url that Hygraph provided, but now all the requests I had made on the account will not allow me to make any more requests for me to save money on my first project being built using Hygraph. My first time using Hygraph, they told me to setup a throttle. I wasn't sure where to begin, but I got to setup and understood a little bit, but I ran into an error message that stopped me from working on my project.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import pThrottle from "p-throttle";
import App from './app.js';

// Throttle fetches to a maximum of 1 concurrent request and
// a minimum delay of 500 milliseconds between requests.

const throttledFetch = pThrottle((...args) => {
  console.log(throttledFetch);
  return fetch(...args);
}, 1, 5000);

const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
  fetch: throttledFetch,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Trying to console but not showing anything in my DevTool. I don't know what going on within this code that making the error come up in the first place.

Comment: An I keep change the number so many time still nothing.